# ASP.NET MVC4 OAuth Microsoft (Live) account - get users emails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, windows-live-id, liveid

I'm trying to implement OAuth authentication with Microsoft ID for my ASP.NET MVC4 web site. So far, the log in with Microsoft account works. But I need to get some extra user data (specifically, users account or preferred email address).

I'm using live.domains as my email service. So I created emails for my users with my domain. Now I want to enable those users to log in to the site using their email accounts (with OAuth).

*Note: my web server doesn't support asp.net 4.5, so I'm stuck on 4.0, and can't use the LiveSDK for ASP.NET (as far as I know)...*

The idea is something like is:

- use the built in OAuth functionality to log users in
- get their account email address, and check if it is an email from my domain
- if it isn't from my domain, refuse registration
- if the email is from my domain, allow the user to register and proceed normaly

I created a custom Microsoft OAuth2Client, using the default as reference (default clients can be found on [github](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OAuth2)), and specified the required scopes (wl.basic, wl.signin, wl.emails). The rest of the code is pretty much the same.

```
public MyMicrosoftClient(string appId, string appSecret)
    : this(appId, appSecret, new string[] {"wl.basic", "wl.signin", "wl.emails"})
{
}
```

The GetUserData function is used to get the extra user data (like name, gender), and that works. Code from default client:

```
protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
{
    MicrosoftClientUserData graph;
    var request =
        WebRequest.Create("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" + CustomHelpers.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(accessToken));
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        graph = JsonHelper.Deserialize<MicrosoftClientUserData>(responseStream);
    }
}

var userData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
userData.Add("id", graph.Id == "" ? null : graph.Id);
userData.Add("username", graph.Name == "" ? null : graph.Name);
userData.Add("name", graph.Name == "" ? null : graph.Name);
userData.Add("link", graph.Link == null ? null : graph.Link.AbsoluteUri);
userData.Add("gender", graph.Gender == "" ? null : graph.Gender);
userData.Add("firstname", graph.FirstName == "" ? null : graph.FirstName);
userData.Add("lastname", graph.LastName == "" ? null : graph.LastName);

return userData;
```

}

My understanding is that this gets all the requested user data (based on specified scopes), so it should also contain the emails in the response. Unfortunately, even if it does, I have no idea how to get that info from the response stream...

So, how would I read the emails from the response (if I'm on the right track at all)?

Comment: Check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17380383/1204249