# Getting email from oauth authentication (Microsoft)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

How can I get the email from microsoft account? I'm doing the following:

```
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
//...

string email = null;
                if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "google")
                {
                    email = result.ExtraData["email"];
                }
                else if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "facebook")
                {
                    email = result.ExtraData["username"];
                }
                else if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "microsoft")
                {
                    email = result.ExtraData["????"];
                }    
}
```

For google and facebook I'm able to get the email but I can't with microsoft? What kew should I use?

Comment: You could add code to trace out all the extra data included and try it yourself? But you can't guarantee the user will have given whichever login provider permission to share their email address with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class MicrosoftScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
    {
        private string clientId;
        private string clientSecret;
        private string scope;

        private const string baseUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf";
        private const string tokenUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf";

        public MicrosoftScopedClient(string clientId, string clientSecret, string scope)
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        public string ProviderName
        {
            get { return "Microsoft"; }
        }

        public void RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
        {
            string url = baseUrl + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scope) + "&response_type=code";
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }

        public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

            string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.ToString();
            //From this we need to remove code portion
            rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

            IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, rawUrl);

            if (userData == null)
                return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

            string id = userData["id"];
            string username = userData["email"];
            userData.Remove("id");
            userData.Remove("email");

            AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
            return result;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
        {
            string token = QueryAccessToken(redirectURI, accessCode);
            if (token == null || token == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            var userData = GetUserData(token);
            return userData;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
        {
            ExtendedMicrosoftClientUserData graph;
            var request =
                WebRequest.Create(
                    "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(accessToken));
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        graph = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtendedMicrosoftClientUserData>(data);
                    }
                }
            }

            var userData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            userData.Add("id", graph.Id);
            userData.Add("username", graph.Name);
            userData.Add("name", graph.Name);
            userData.Add("link", graph.Link == null ? null : graph.Link.AbsoluteUri);
            userData.Add("gender", graph.Gender);
            userData.Add("firstname", graph.FirstName);
            userData.Add("lastname", graph.LastName);
            userData.Add("email", graph.Emails.Preferred);
            return userData;
        }

        private string QueryAccessToken(string returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            var entity =
                CreateQueryString(
                    new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        { "client_id", this.clientId },
                        { "redirect_uri", returnUrl },
                        { "client_secret", this.clientSecret},
                        { "code", authorizationCode },
                        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                    });

            WebRequest tokenRequest = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);
            tokenRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            tokenRequest.ContentLength = entity.Length;
            tokenRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream requestStream = tokenRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
                writer.Write(entity);
                writer.Flush();
            }

            HttpWebResponse tokenResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tokenRequest.GetResponse();
            if (tokenResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = tokenResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        var tokenData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuth2AccessTokenData>(data);
                        if (tokenData != null)
                        {
                            return tokenData.AccessToken;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static readonly string[] UriRfc3986CharsToEscape = new[] { "!", "*", "'", "(", ")" };
        private static string EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(string value)
        {
            StringBuilder escaped = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

            // Upgrade the escaping to RFC 3986, if necessary.
            for (int i = 0; i < UriRfc3986CharsToEscape.Length; i++)
            {
                escaped.Replace(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i], Uri.HexEscape(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i][0]));
            }

            // Return the fully-RFC3986-escaped string.
            return escaped.ToString();
        }

        private static string CreateQueryString(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> args)
        {
            if (!args.Any())
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(args.Count() * 10);

            foreach (var p in args)
            {
                sb.Append(EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(p.Key));
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(p.Value));
                sb.Append('&');
            }
            sb.Length--; // remove trailing &

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        protected class ExtendedMicrosoftClientUserData
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public Uri Link { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Emails Emails { get; set; }
        }

        protected class Emails
        {
            public string Preferred { get; set; }
            public string Account { get; set; }
            public string Personal { get; set; }
            public string Business { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**AuthConfig.cs**

```
public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {

            Dictionary<string, object> MicrosoftsocialData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            MicrosoftsocialData.Add("Icon", "../Content/icons/microsoft.png");

            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new MicrosoftScopedClient("XXXXXXXX", "YYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                "wl.basic wl.emails"), "Microsoft", MicrosoftsocialData);

            //......
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
//...

string email = null;
                if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "google")
                {
                    email = result.ExtraData["email"];
                }
                else if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "facebook")
                {
                    email = result.ExtraData["username"];
                }
                else if (result.Provider.ToLower() == "microsoft")
                {
                    email = result.UserName;
                }    
}
```

Based on: [How OAuthWebSecurity to obtain emails for different oauth clients, but Microsoft Client doesn’t return email, it didn’t include scope “wl.emails”](http://mvcdiary.com/2013/03/01/how-oauthsecurity-to-obtain-emails-for-different-oauth-clients-but-microsoft-client-doesnt-return-email-it-didnt-include-scope-wl-emails/)

Comment: I have tried using the code you have provided but on get of the result I am getting a The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request error bombing out on HttpWebResponse tokenResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tokenRequest.GetResponse(); any ideas?

Comment: +1 Now this works fine and I am getting email address but now `firstname` and `lastname` are coming out as blank.

Answer (score 4):

or even simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723713/1586498

```
var mo =
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CallbackPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Callbacks/External"),//register at oAuth provider
                ClientId = "<<yourclientid>>",
                ClientSecret = "<<yourclientsecret>>",
                Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(providerKey, context.Identity.AuthenticationType));
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                }
            };
mo.Scope.Add("wl.basic");  
mo.Scope.Add("wl.emails");  //HERE IS THE GOLD

app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(mo);
```

and my way of grabbing them:

```
var externalIdentity = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
externalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email));
```

Answer (score 0):

amp's answer really helped me out.

Also want to mention that you have to check the 'Live SDK support' checkbox when you register your application (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) - otherwise the OAuth service complains that you don't have a client secret (even if you do).

Just wanted to add how to do this without using the AuthConfig.cs stuff in case anyone is interested (a bit more manual, but it makes it easier to understand if you're not familiar with the framework):

```
public ActionResult LoginWithMicrosoftAccount(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var client = new MicrosoftScopedClient(appID, appsecret, "wl.basic wl.emails");
    var urlNoQueryString = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    if(Request.QueryString["error"]!= null)
    {//Microsoft service returns error
        return View();
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
    {
        result = client.VerifyAuthentication(this.HttpContext);

        //at this point, you should get the username from result.UserName
    }
    if(Request.QueryString["code"]==null || result.UserName == null)
    {//will do the redirection
        client.RequestAuthentication(this.HttpContext, new Uri(urlNoQueryString));
    }
    return View();
}
```