# Get E-mail of User Authenticated with Microsoft Account in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using the ASP.NET Identity stuff that came with the new MVC 5 templates in VS2013. I've configured external login providers so people can sign up using Google, Facebook, or Microsoft. However, I would still like to get peoples' e-mail address (e.g. for notifications, updates, etc.).

By default the `app.UseGoogleAuthentication()` will also request the user's e-mail address. For Facebook, I've created a new instance of the `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` class, and added the following scope: `facebook.Scope.Add("email")`. This also works.

I'm having problems getting the e-mail for people using a Microsoft Account. The `MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions` also has a `Scope` property, but adding `email` doesn't seem to work. In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826526.aspx) I see there is a scope `wl.emails` but it returns an array of e-mail addresses and I'm not sure if this is the equivalent for `email` with Facebook.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to get the e-mail address as a claim when authenticating?

Comment: In Windows Accounts you had a list of mails, not just one unique mail. It's a list of emails taking the rol of aliases for the account.
You can't get further information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Configure the scopes for Microsoft.

   ```
   var mo = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
   {
       Caption = "Live",
       ClientId = clientId,
       ClientSecret = clientSecret,
   };

   mo.Scope.Add("wl.basic");
   mo.Scope.Add("wl.emails");

   app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(mo);
   ```
2. Grab the email claim

   ```
   var identity = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   var emailClaim = identity.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
   ```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Adding the scope statements causes the following error message to show up on the Microsoft Login page: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope wl.basic wl.emails is not valid.

Comment: @DavidWGray I switched to .NET Core as everything works as expected there.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new   MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "Your_client_id",
            ClientSecret = "your_client_secret_key",
            Scope = { "wl.basic", "wl.emails" }
        });
```

and to get email

```
 var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

string email=externalIdentity.Result.Email;
```

Comment: This does not work anymore. Adding the scope statements causes the following error message to show up on the Microsoft Login page: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope wl.basic wl.emails is not valid.