# ASP .NET MVC 5 Identity - Microsoft login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to create a login with Microsoft and get the user's email. My application works perfectly but I can not get the person's email.
If I use the following code, I can log in with Microsoft, but I can not get the email.

```
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "*",
        ClientSecret = "*"
    });
```

If I use this code (I found it in some forum), I get the following error when I want to log in with Microsoft

```
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "*",
        ClientSecret = "*",
        Scope = { "wl.emails" }
    });
```

[Error login image](https://preview.ibb.co/inrb0Q/6oDgq.png)

I added the "email" permission, but I do not know if it is correct

[Email permission](https://image.ibb.co/neQEn5/Captura.jpg)

Some help? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the identity user if it has got a claim for email address?

Comment: Here is one SO post that might give you some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229593/get-e-mail-of-user-authenticated-with-microsoft-account-in-asp-net-identity

Comment: @TejSoft Hi and thx! I already read that thread and tried that solution, but it still does not work. I get the same error and **"Have you checked the identity user if it has got a claim for email address?"**, how to check that? Thx!